# .Net CoreApp: Simple String Builder That'll Build My HTML

Tags: c#, html, json, .net-core

**I need simple String Builder to build my HTML ,
**USING CONSOLE APPLICATION** .**

Want to try, need your help !  :)

Just have 2 separate -> it's my **Html**, and **C# .netcoreapp2.1 app** ...

I wanna to know how to interact with each other,

In this case I have **JSON** data ...

**JSON:**

```
   {
      "generatedOn": "2020-04-05 10:11:36",
      "agent": "G1a"
    }
    {
      "generatedOn": "2020-04-05 10:15:32",
      "agent": "G2"
    }
```

In HTML i planning to print them dynamically print all these to :

```
<ul>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

So yes ... i need From **.Net Core** send *Array.. List* ... Of data -> to **HTML** (index.html)

Looking forward for any suggestions how to do it, my **.Net core** file is empty at the moment.  :)

**.Net Core**

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

PS. Json data i will grab later from every separate files and will parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this this

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonData); 
//convert your json to a list or a string
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.html", FileMode.Create)) 
    { 
       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8)) // creates the file
            { 
                sw.WriteLine(@"<H1>HTML template for showing json data</H1>"); // or you can have a list of strings and add lines of html code to it then put it all as one string here
                sw.WriteLine($"<p>data = {data}</p>"); // if its a list have a for loop and add li elements
         
        
            } 
        }
```

if you open data.html your browser opens it up

Comment: No ... I need create HTML file for our CEO worker ,who will just grab this file and see the results.

Comment: So what you console app is doing is fetching the data here?

Comment: it fetching JSON data ... this data i'll get by reading another mini-files

Comment: After that i'll parse it ... but not it general idea now.. now general idea is how to create String Builder .. that will , add them to my html

Comment: If I understood correctly, HTML is just a template here to show data. Your project is not a web app at all. You could create a custom html page with all elements and everything through your console app and save it as a html file somewhere on your disc. Would you like to see a demo of that? Is that what we are doing here?

Comment: sure every example is welcome .. ;) 
but using console app and customizing custom html file .. without localhosts etc.. please . :)

Comment: Got it. I wanna make sure I actually answer your question. Does this html file exist already and we are making adjustments on it? Or do we make one from scratch and save it every time the app is run?

Comment: If you want to create a new file every time you can pit the date as its file name. That way you have a full history of all data requests with their data and the dates all saved up in a folder.

Comment: let's try do Create .. Because it'll be only 1 launch , after it .. these old JSON files not be to use anymore

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a real need for a seperate net core project I would look at using asp net core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows

Hard to tell what you want to do.

Comment: no .. i need make addition tool, for real ready core project...

Comment: it's .cshtml  ... i need edit and work with .html ...

Comment: Can you give more detail on the architecture? If you want to move some html from a console project to "something else" there are many ways to do it but without knowing your setup this is guess work.

EDIT: .cshtml is just the file extension asp net core still works with and outputs html

Comment: so ok it's could be .cshtml , but not local .. 
i junt need to Edit / Generate new HTML , with added Data

Comment: it will be just simple Console App .. after running i'll get edited/correct version of html

Comment: i don't really now know how to send any data from c# to html

Comment: in html i can use Jquery with this got data array, u know

Comment: to display them dynamically

Comment: Ok then you just need to load a data file, parse the json then write the output to a file?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0
Then just save as a string and write it out using File.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-5.0

Comment: exactly .. now i have metadata.json , metadata2.json, metadata3.json files in everyone i have a parameters of generatedOn and agen variables....

Comment: i think i just need to read them ... and add to StringBuilder ... after that just Create a new HTML files .. and i think that's all at the moment ... ;)